# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in

Tags: php

I currently have this code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$songs->PLAYEDAT) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $songs->TITLE . '<br />';
```

But the problem is that it gives me that error in the title.. i tried many things and i can't get it to work properly..

If i echo out $songs->PLAYEDAT it gives me a number..which is an unixtimestamp i know for sure..because in D.N.A.S shoutcast stats thing it shows the date..how they do it ? i don't know.

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($songs->PLAYEDAT)` to see what's in that property?

Comment: `long` means a *number*. The error clearly says that it wants a number and doesn't know what to do with the object you're giving it instead.

Comment: It's a number,an unix timestamp. 1373474832

Comment: @user2566002 - try as Kolink suggested, and `var_dump($songs->PLAYEDAT)`

Comment: @Kolink object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "1373475742"
}

Comment: @user2566002 Well there you go. That's an object, not a number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The variable you supplied (`$songs->PLAYEDAT`) is probably a string or at best a DateTime object.

If it's a DateTime object:

```
$songs->PLAYEDAT->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

If it's a string representation of a date:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($songs->PLAYEDAT))
```

**UPDATE:** Answer specific to this question copied back from comment below

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($songs->PLAYEDAT[0]))
```

Comment: None of those above work..

Comment: It's an object. The error message tells him it's an object.

Comment: @user2566002 can you do a `var_dump(get_class($songs->PLAYEDAT))`?

Comment: string(16) "SimpleXMLElement"

Comment: then the answer is `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $songs->PLAYEDAT[0])`

Comment: @Populus still the same.

Comment: then the answer is `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($songs->PLAYEDAT[0]))`, we're really baby-sitting you here :/

Comment: @Populus that actally works..if you don't want to help me or "baby-sit" me as you say then don't.